# How to show the output in multiple text files in python, for example: print digits from 1 to 10 in 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, output, text-files

How to show the output in multiple text files in python, for example: print digits from 1 to 10 in 1.txt(o/p-1),2.txt(o/p-2),3.txt(o/p-3) files...
Here is a piece of code that I tried, to get the image files as text and store it in individual folders.

```
     c=-1

     outFile=[] //created a list,as it would overwrite the same outfile multiple times if not used(expecting it to be a different file when list is used)


     for i in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
                

   `     
         text = pytesseract.image_to_string(images[i])

         c=c+1

         outFile.append(c)

         outFile[c] = open(str1+"outputfile.txt", "w")//str values could be incremented using a different loop/function to have difference in name.
  
         outFile[c].write(text)

         outFile[c].close()
```

Any modification or new approach is really appreciated.

Comment: `str(c)` converts the number ro a string which can then be concatenated with other strings to build path (if necessary) and filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in images:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(i)
    with open(f"{i}.txt", w) as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Assumption:

1. We will save the text files (1.txt, 2.txt, .... ) in current directory.
2. **images** is an array containing multiple images (not the physical location)